# USB Connected Device - Device Control

Tags: usb-on-the-go, usb-c

I purchased a USB C thumbdrive to make transferring images off my phone (Galaxy S10) a little simpler.
However, upon being prompted for the "Charging Connected Device Via USB" for "USB Settings" USB is controlled by "Connected Device" instead of "This Device".  I still went in to my developer options and changed the "Use USB For" default so I can "transfer files/Android Auto", however I still can't successfully change "USB Controlled by".

It prompts me to "Restart Your Phone" stating "a USB storage device was removed unsafely. To prevent your phone from restarting unexpectedly, save unsaved data and restart now"... but it won't allow me to switch, and restarting has no effect.

This USB only does this when attached to my phone- my computer doesn't have the same issue.  Formatting the USB had no effect, and **I couldn't find any saved connection** in my phone to delete to see if it
would forget this setting.

Is there anyone that can help? I have tried looking into this issue and I can't find any help online.